# Legend in QGIS sometimes does not show palette

Tags: qgis, legend

For some of my elevation maps the legend does show the palette, and for others it doesn't.
I am viewing the legend in the Map Layout.

Comment: Well, did you make sure to include the not shown layers in the legend, or did you forget?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The maps (rasters) which had a Color Band were Grd Files, whereas the one i could not see a color band had a format as XYZ. I noticed this difference after looking at the different properties of each raster, and I noticed the file type which were different.  I then Saved As the XYZ file format to a grd file and it worked!